# Is PIN-protected token with login certificate a two-factor authentication if the token is controlled solely by the user?

Tags: authentication, token

I know it isn't since the service the user is authenticating to cannot check the PIN correctness or existence. I need, however, to explain this to people who are convinced this actually *is* a two-factor authentication, since the user is *required* to use PIN by Terms and Conditions. Is there preferably some kind of "authoritative" definition I could build my argumentation on? Found only NIST 800-63-2 but it's inconclusive in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by "PIN-protected token"? By my understanding of your question, I would say that it is indeed 2FA.

Comment: "the service [...] cannot check the PIN correctness or existence" -- so users type in a PIN/token-code but the service is set to completely ignore the field?  So this isn't authentication at all (besides the cert)?

Comment: Neither. There is an arbitrary token which may or may not be pin-protected or may not even be present. The application only challenges the user for having access to the private key of his respective certificate. However, since users are "required" to have the certificate on a token and pin-protected, the business owner of the application is convinced he in fact has 2FA. Which he has not, since the app does not and can not technically check for pin protection let alone enforce it. The "2FA" in this case is purely ToS-based, not technical.

Answer (score 1):

If they cannot understand that the scenario is faulty, it might be better to side-step the 2FA argument and simply stick with the much simpler argument that having any factor that is insecure makes it a null method.

In this case, unless you can **enforce** a strong PIN or passcode when creating the certificate, you can be certain that lazy people (most of us after all!) WILL not bother. Leaving the certificate wide open to copying & unwanted reuse.

UPDATE: From your comments.

The first thing to do is to make sure your own butt is covered by raising a formal risk if you have a suitable process available. Otherwise by at least ensuring you have written proof that you raised the issue.

The Next step might be to try and encourage the organisation to have an external security review. Internal Audit departments can be very helpful here! They generally are very grateful to anyone who will willingly speak to them and are often more than happy to take a steer from you regarding organisational risks.

Not every problem has a direct answer :/

Comment: Oh believe me I've tried. They think by "enforcing" users via ToS somehow magically makes the whole scenario 2FA-grade secure and they stick with it using arguments I have yet to dispel. All of their arguments are reactive though, such as "in case of trial the user will have to prove he used a PIN". 
This gets even more interesting in regards of pro-arguments as the certificate is "qualified", meaning it is issued by an authority "trusted" by the government and the certificate-based signature is formally recognized as a legal signature. Which of course yields more demagogic argumentation.

Comment: Ah! I've come across this myself. Security by butt-covering! Time for a change of job?!

Comment: lol, security by butt-covering, love the term :) I like the job, this is just a small part of it. I'd rather go for a solution since this may have impact on quite a few people who have no choice but to go with this app. Chickening out is not an option here.

Comment: Feel free to use the term, no charge :)  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Cheers for the update. I can't go in too much detail here but let's just say it's ... sensitive to the corporation. Hence the need for an "authoritative proof" which I wasn't able to come up with just yet as my expertise clearly isn't enough. In current situation there is no way to escalate the issue in order for it to have any reasonable impact. These high level solutions go above my pay grade, my only take on this is convincing business owners and since as I play the role of auditor in this case I have to back my claims by "authorities". Apparently my 7+y expertise doesn't count as one.

Comment: Looks like you might be stuck for now then. Make sure you retain copies of emails on the subject. Look for opportunities to get an external security review and slip this issue into it. Don't give up, sometimes it takes a year or two to slowly move things in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Two factor authentication is requiring 2 out of three factors of authentication from either:
1. Something you know 
2. Something you have
3. Something you are (biometric)

Two factor is not a silver bullet though, as was mentioned because a factor can still be weak. The risk of having a weak 'something you know' is partially mitigated if you still have to have something like the certificate.  I am still in favor of a strong 'something you know' as well because a four character PIN allows for only 10,000 combinations. Protections have to be in place to prevent brute forcing or offline attacks if the item is stolen.  Would it be possible to require the PIN for the cert and then require an additional strong password?

I think though if push comes to shove a PIN combined with something you have like a token cert is still more secure than a password by itself.  An attacker only has to steal the password if that is the only factor. In two factor the attacker has to steal the token with certificate and then get then pin as well.  People will hopefully report their token is missing since they can no longer get access and the old token can be removed, so even if they were able to get in they would need to get more credentials or methods to maintain persistence.